# Calculating Big-O time and space complexity for functional languages

Tags: functional-programming, runtime, ocaml

I'm thinking of using Ocaml for technical interviews in the future. However, I'm not sure how to calculate time and space complexity for functional languages. What are the basic runtimes for the basic higher level functions like map, reduce, and filter, and how do I calculate runtime and space complexity in general?

Comment: IMHO this is too general a question for Stack Overflow, but is an amazingly excellent question :-) You can usually find complexities given in the library documentation for standard functions like map. There is a classic book on the subject: Purely Functional Data Structures, Chris Okasaki. I found it really enlightening.

Comment: Ah, thank you! To be honest, I've been Googling it for a while and didn't know where to get started, so of course Stack Overflow was the best place I thought I could ask it.

Comment: Depends you whether you mean complexity of the implementation, or based on lambda calculus: for theory see [here](https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/questions/376/using-lambda-calculus-to-derive-time-complexity), expecially the recent paper by dal Lago and Accatoli; for implementation have a look at [The Implementation of Functional Programming Languages](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/research/publication/the-implementation-of-functional-programming-languages/?from=http%3A%2F%2Fresearch.microsoft.com%2Fen-us%2Fum%2Fpeople%2Fsimonpj%2Fpapers%2Fslpj-book-1987%2Fstart.htm)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The time complexity of persistent recursive implementations is easy to infer directly from the implementation. In this case, the recursive definition maps directly to the recurrence relation. Consider the `List.map` function as it is implemented in the Standard Library:

```
let rec map f = function
  | [] -> []
  | a::l -> f a :: map f l
```

The complexity is `map(N) = 1 + map (N-1)` thus it is O(N).

Speaking of the space complexity it is not always that obvious, as it requires an understanding of tail-calls and a skill to see the allocations. The general rule is that in OCaml native integers, characters, and constructors without arguments do no allocate the heap memory, everything else is allocated in the heap and is boxed. All non-tail calls create a stack frame and thus consume the stack space. In our case, the complexity of the `map` in the stack domain is O(N), as it makes N non-tail calls. The heap-complexity is also O(N) as the `::` operator is invoked N times.

Another place, where space is consumed are closures. If a function has at least one free variable (i.e., a variable that is not bound to function parameters and is not in the global scope), then a functional object called closure is created, that contains a pointer to the code and a pointer to each free variable (also called the captured variable).

For example, consider the following function:

```
 let rec rsum = function
   | [] -> 0
   | x :: xs -> 
     List.fold_left (fun y -> x + y) 0 xs + rsum xs
```

For each element of a list, this function computes a sum this element, with all consecutive elements. The naive implementation above is O(N) in the stack (as each step has two non-tail calls), O(N) in the heap size, as each step constructs a new closure (unless the compiler is clever enough to optimize it). Finally, it is O(N^2) in the time domain (`rsum(N) = (N-1) + rsum(N-1)`).

However, it brings a question - should we take into account a garbage, that is produced by a computation? I.e., those values, that were allocated, during the computation, but are not referenced by it. Or those values, that are referenced only during a step, as in this case. So it all depends on the model of computation that you chose. If you will choose a reference counting GC, then the example above is definitely O(1) in the heap size.

Hope this will give some insights. Feel free to ask questions, if something is not clear.

Comment: Good answer, but I think one part of the space analysis isn't quite correct. The closures allocated by the `rsum` function become garbage before the recursive call is performed. Typical cost models would budget this as O(1) heap use, because the _live_ heap data fits into constant space.

Comment: Well, yes, when I was writing this, I was thinking about that. Whether we should take a pure garbage into the model. Depending on the GC configuration it may outlive the computation, so it can be live after the function is evaluated. Moreover, the garbage, produced during computation, basically induce a time complexity penalty (however, from the perspective of Big-O it is not a problem, as the penalty should have the complexity that is no bigger that the complexity of the computation itself). So in practice, this really matters, but in theory, I think that you're right.

Comment: Agreed about the GC adding time, but as you say, it is amortized with the allocations (for any GC strategy), so doesn't change Big-O. One more nit: the usual definition of "live" does not include garbage, even if it hasn't been collected yet.